# Create apps in VB.NET without .net framework

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have learned to create programs in VB.NET with Visual Studio,
but the downside of that is that i need the .NET framework, which is not on every computer.
Can I create a program in VB.NET without it needing the .NET framework?
If yes, what tools do i need?

Comment: Visual Basic 6?? Seriously, .NET is free, I don't see why it would be a big issue to install it on computers that will run your program.

Comment: The last 4 characters of 'VB.NET' should answer your question.

Comment: @Meta-Knight the classic complaint is that it's a pretty big thing to add to the download/install for a consumer app.  people just don't have the patience for stuff like that in this world of powerful web apps.  The "client profile" was created to mitigate this pain though

Comment: @RobertLevy Agreed, not to mention that Vista / Windows 7 both ship with the .NET Framework 3.0, so if you really want to reduce the chance of it not being installed, targeting .NET 2.0 or 3.0 should help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but the downside of that is that i need the .NET framework, which is not on every computer.

Include an installer for your program that will install the .NET Framework if it's needed. MSDN has a nice article on how to do that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx

> Can I create a program in VB without it needing the .NET framework?

Assuming you mean VB.NET, then no, not really. The Microsoft VB.NET compiler compiles to an intermediate language, and your code probably has hundreds of dependencies on the .NET Framework itself. There are *other* Frameworks like Mono that you could use, but they also must be installed, and have a much less-likely chance of already being installed.

Answer (score -1):

VB6 don't need .NET framework and will run on any Windows and MSSQL version (even on a 64 bit).

You can use the latest ador and adodb drivers installed on it (MS Office), but VB.NET is the way to go and you can't create an app without the .NET framework.

The .NET framework is free and you just include it on your setup (as mentioned).

Comment: Using VB6 is very very bad idea.